# Can I make new methods dynamicly in a loop or in an other matter

Tags: java, loops, methods

In school we have to make a program, which is that you type in personal information, such as namn, age and so on. And you have one button where you save information and one where you type out.

I save this information like this:

- Person.name = Name.getText();
- Person.age = age.getText();
- Person.sex = sex.getText();

And then i have a method. Which takes this information and saves it. Because there is only one button to save information. Can you make new mothods for every new person you save? Should you do it in a loop. That loops out new methods everytime you press? And how.

Thx

Comment: You have to work with Objects i guess?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to 'make new methods' each time you want to save the Person data. The point is to create a method which is dynamic, that means you have to have access to the Person class/data and just do as you defined: person.setName(name.getText());

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a new method everytime you save, you need a new Person object. The method that gets called when save is pressed should accept Person as a parameter. So save is pressed it creates a new Person object and populates it like u already do, Person.name = Name.getText();, Person.age = age.getText(); and so on. That populated Person object is then passed to a method  which has all the code to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make new method every time, what you need to do is just make a class named `Person` and define its attributes as `Name`, `Age` and `Sex` and make methods that access this variables and sets this variables, as I've shown below:

```
class Person{
   String Name="";
   String Age="";
   String Sex="";

   public String getName(){
    return Name;
   }

   public String setName(String Name){
    this.Name=Name;
   }

   public String getAge(){
    return Age;
   }

   public String setAge(String Age){
    this.Age=Age;
   }

   public String getSex(){
    return Name;
   }

   public String setName(String Sex){
    this.Sex=Sex;
   }


}
```

You can access this methods and variables by just making object of this `Person` class as:

```
Class UsePerson{
  public static void main(String ar[]){
    Person p=new Person();
    p.setName("ABC");   //Here You set the Name of the person
    String name=p.getName();   //Here you'll get the name of Person

  }
}
```